# HTML & CSS - Moving objects to specific position

Tags: html, css

I recently started to make a web-server, I'm usually working with back-end code, but now I got a project to do. I'm still very green on CSS and HTML. So basically I need to somehow move the bank logo down and the Label - "Maze bank of Los-Santos" a bit closer to the logo, I have researched a lot of, but I still don't understand the working principle of the position, width, display, margin, top sometimes work, sometimes doesn't, at some times I use right, left positioning, but at this point I don't know how to do it.

This is how my website looks:
[image]

My index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style2.css">
    <title>Maze bank - Log In</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/hm8Fz83/bank.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calistoga&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hm8Fz83/bank.png"></img>
    <p><span style="color:white">Maze Bank Of </span>Los-Santos</p>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/test?category=computers" method="POST" target="_blank">
            <div class="login-box">
                <div class="textbox">
                    <i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Bill Number" name="bill" value="" maxlength="15" minlength="15" >
                </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Pincode" name="pin" value="" maxlength="4" minlength="4">
            </div>
            <button class="link">Forgot password ?</button>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Log in">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
            <h4>©™ 2019 Copyright All Rights Reserved</h4>
         </div>
</body>
</html>**strong text**
```

Here's my CSS Code:

```
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";

p{
    display:block;
    color: #2ECC71;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-block: 2px solid black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #1a1111;
}

p:first-letter{ 
    display:block; 
    /*adjust the letter position for best appearance*/
    margin:4px 4px 0 5px!important;  
    /*set font family color and size*/
    color:#2ECC71; 
    font-size:1.5em; 
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
}


html, body{

    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    background: url(https://external-preview.redd.it/ar2z7yTm97BFzRtPJXWA_twAbm-DlDKUt3mS0R8aJtY.png?auto=webp&s=c965a508182b77fbdec96dd82d6ed224a3b17543) no-repeat fixed center;
}

.logo{
    font-family: fantasy;
}

.login-box{
    width: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

.textbox{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e16a74;

}

.textbox i {
    width: 26px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;

}

.textbox input{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    background: #e16a74;
    border: 2px solid #e16a74;
    margin: 12px 0 ;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;

}
.btn {border-radius: 12px;}

.copyright {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    bottom:0;
}

.copyright h4{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10;
    text-align: center;
}


.login-box button.link
{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color: wheat;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1000%;
    left:55%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsts, [check your code to be valid](https://validator.w3.org) :) For example, `<img>` element [should not have a closing tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element). You should always try to have valid html because html with errors can affect rendering in browsers.

Secondly, I see that you added a `<br>` after `<body>` and before `<img>`. Possibly this is to make a small margin above the logo. Don't do that because this way you will never get a reliable distance from the top across browsers. Remove `<br>` and use `margin-top: 16px` or so style in your css for `img`.

Next, give a css class to your `p` element, like `<p class="bank-name">` and style it in css:

```css
.bank-name {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This `p` is very specific, so you should give it a dedicated class because you can have other `<p>`s on the page that do not need the same appearance.

Two more things:

1. Avoid inline styles in html.
2. Do not use `!important` unless you have a huge reason to do it.

Also `<p>` is `block` by default, so you do not need that `display: block` in html. You can often find default styles at [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp).

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time and help:)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a `div` tag to regroup your image and text. That `div` must have `display: block` so that the text won't be on the same line, but under. Now depending of the width of the image, you will probably need to align the text with `text-align: center`

You can read more about css rules on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

```css
img {
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hm8Fz83/bank.png"></img>
  <p><span>Maze Bank Of </span>Los-Santos</p>
</div>
```